# GAE runs locally but gives 403 error when uploaded

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a Google App Engine application that runs locally and when uploaded.
 In order to make a certain kind of experiment, I make a copy of it and it runs locally, but when I upload it (to a different web location) I get a `403` error. I am stumped. 
Has anyone else using GAE encountered this problem? 
Is there some clever way to use the browser debugger to get more information about the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It was just a stupid mistake, so never mind. Sorry.